# Не переходит на страницу меток tag.php в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему при нажатии на какую либо из меток, выдает ошибку 404, если шаблон для меток tag.php в WordPress был создан ??

Или необходимо дополнительную функцию прописывать в functions.php ??

Страница поста с двумя тестовыми метками
https://delavcom.com/why-lead-generation-is-key-for-business-growth/blogs_box-en/

Comment: в метках язык проставлен?

Comment: Вопрос решен. Так как сайт мультиязычный, нужно было в плагине Polylang в  URL modifications, пересохранить настройки.